# IntelliJ IDEA Flash APP - how do I manage the "emulator" list in Run/Debug config?

Tags: flash, air, intellij-idea

I would like to have many preset emulator options here, i.e., to have available across multiple projects.  Where do I manage this list?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list is hardcoded and you can't manage it.

Here is the [related feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113605), please vote.